# Multiple DLL calls in VBA

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I've created a C++ DLL with many Functions and I call them from excel sheet through VBA. The Problem I'm facing is the following:

I have many spreadsheet cells calling the same function at the same time every N seconds,it is taking a while to update the excel book. If called separately each run is very efficient however when multiple cells calls the function it runs serialized and takes too long.

My question is, how can I get better solution?  I thought if its possible the same function be called simultaneously and run on parallel or something like that, so I can the routine faster.

Thanks

Comment: There's exactly one thread available to any VBA code, and Excel itself is running an STA thread. "simultaneously" or "parallel" isn't a possibility.

Comment: instead of calling the c++ DLL separately for each use in a cell, could you call the DLL function on a timed basis and get the information for all of the cells in one go? The cell functions could then refer to the most recent set of data returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your C++ functions directly callable multi-threaded UDFs in an XLL: then Excel's calculation engine will exploit multi-threading using multiple cores.

To do this you will need to use the Excel 'C' Api SDK

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687829.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687883.aspx